# Basic Component annotation in Spring does not work?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I'm just starting to study Spring framework and while I was playing around with the very basic code, I keep getting this error that I am unable to understand why I am getting despite being sure it should not happen.  I cannot find any clear answer from the web why I am getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.my.learning.MathComponent' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1150)
        at com.my.learning.LearningApplication.main(LearningApplication.java:22)

I have put a component annotation in a class and I am simply trying to call this class.  I don't understand why I am getting the error:
```

The code I am trying is below.

```
package com.my.learning;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LearningApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(LearningApplication.class, args);
        MathComponent ms = context.getBean(MathComponent.class);
        ms.displayMessage();

    }

}
```

```
package com.my.learning;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MathComponent {
    
    public void displayMessage(){
        System.out.println("this is the math class");
    }
    
}
```

Can I seek help here to understand what I am missing?

Comment: which spring boot version are you using?

Comment: Running with Spring Boot v3.1.0-M1, Spring v6.0.5